# MS Graph API message move - 415 unsupported media type

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-415

I have followed proper documentation and examples. Also other methods are working fine, but message move is not working properly. Please look at below and suggest what I should change:

```
PS C:\> $body = @{
>>   "destinationId" = "$folderid"   
>> }
## Note: I have tried well known folder types also like deleteditems
PS C:\> $body

Name                           Value
----                           -----
destinationId                  AAMkADIzYjU1MDg4LWIzOTAtNDVhYi1iNjczLTdlNjBiMjExMGE3MwAuAAAAAAAMiK_sOzYGRJ9qF2G24SoEA...


$urimove="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/mymailbox@xyz.com/messages/$conv/move"

$body = @{
  "destinationId" = "$folderid"
}

$mv = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $urimove -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Headers $Headers -Body $body

### if I change above -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to "application/json", I start getting 400 bad request error
```

ERROR:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $urimove -ContentType "applicatio ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked... below is the solution:

```
$urimove="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/mailbox@domain.com/messages/$Id/move"

$body = @{
  "destinationId" = "$folderid"
}

$body_json = $body | ConvertTo-Json

$mv = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $urimove -Headers $Headers -Body $body_json
```

Changes are:

1. body should be body_json as shown above
2. no content-type in request call
3. content-type should be in headers and equals application/json